# D3 Line Chart not render like wave

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My line chart is heaving a very minor fluctuation but when I am plotting using D3 it is not working properly and coming as single line:

Can some one please help me as it not working properly.

```
var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 }
      , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right // Use the window's width 
      , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // Use the window's height


    // The number of datapoints
    var n = dataset.length;


    // 5. X scale will use the index of our data
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, n - 1]) // input
      .range([0, width]); // output

    // 6. Y scale will use the randomly generate number 
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 1]) // input 
      .range([height, 0]); // output 

    // 7. d3's line generator
    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function (d, i) { return xScale(i); }) // set the x values for the line generator
      .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.y); }) // set the y values for the line generator 
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) // apply smoothing to the line

    // 8. An array of objects of length N. Each object has key -> value pair, the key being "y" and the value is a random number


    // 1. Add the SVG to the page and employ #2
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // 3. Call the x axis in a group tag
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

    // 4. Call the y axis in a group tag
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft

    // 9. Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator 
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(dataset) // 10. Binds data to the line 
      .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling 
      .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator 

    // 12. Appends a circle for each datapoint 
    svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
      .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
      .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xScale(i) })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d.y) })
      .attr("r", 5)
```

Fiddle link is here

https://jsfiddle.net/ananddeepsingh/52okcewv/1/

Comment: Your data does not have a `y` property:  `yScale(d.y)` should return NaN, which if you inspect the path, you'll see that every coordinate in the path has NaN as the y value. What property are you trying to plot?

Comment: I want to plot single record for example c1 from the dataset

Comment: Your code works then if you change `d.y` to `d.c1` (in both line generator and when placing points) *and* have the domain account for the domain of the input values: [0,4], [for example](https://jsfiddle.net/9xjfuo0g/).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewReid your suggestions worked. Really thankful to you. Can I connect with you on LinkedIn